# SQLite3: Command to view created table in SQLite shell?

Tags: sqlite

I'm new to SQLite3 and would like to verify that the table and columns I have created were actually created.  Is there a shell command that will display the table and columns?  I tried Googling it but all I get is information on creating views.  The .help doesn't appear to have anything that would help me.  I would appreciate any information on this matter.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not that I know of.  You can use this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pragma table_info(YourTable);
```

lists all the columns of your table

To see the create table statement:

```
select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and tbl_name = 'YourTable';
```

Answer (score 0):

From SQLite shell:

```
.schema <TABLE_NAME>
```

will show schema of TABLE_NAME. Remember **not** to place ';' after it.